# excel vba to run a sql command getting selected data from a CSV file

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am trying to run a sql command based on a selected org name from a drop down list , then import all the matching rows from a csv file that have the same org name , I can get it working with a ODBC connection , but it does not work when changing it to a CSV connection , any help would be much appreciated

```vb
Public Const ConnStringCSV = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" & _
"Data Source=T:\DataFeed;" & _
"Extended Properties=""text;HDR=yes;FMT=Delimited(,)"";Persist Security Info=False"
im conn As New ADODB.Connection
Sub import_from_csv()
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim connMasterConnection As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rsObj As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim Ws_FData As Worksheet
Dim Ws_UserForm As Worksheet
Dim strSQL As String
Dim org as String
Dim iCols As Integer
Dim varname1 As String
Dim ops As String

Set Ws_Fdata = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("FData")

    'Delete the last results before we start the new run
Ws_FData.Cells.Clear

    'The value of the organisation that the users chooses
org = Sheet5.Range("A1").Value

connMasterConnection.Open ConnStringCSV

    'varname1 is the SQL Code I need to look for a match in org name from a 
    'search 'list I have , then add all the rows of data
     'The CSV File is called OrgCheck.csv 

rsObj.Open varname1, connMasterConnection, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
For iCols = 0 To rsObj.Fields.Count - 1
Ws_FData.Cells(1, iCols + 1).Value = rsObj.Fields(iCols).Name
Next 
Ws_FData.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rsObj
connMasterConnection.Close`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a missing semi-colon. It should be:

`Public Const ConnStringCSV = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _`